# filtering custom adapter throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

So I have a custom adapter which extends ArrayAdapter. I am trying to use SearchView to filter the from my
ArrayList and if i type in first letter it gets filtered properly but when i type in the second letter the app crashes with IndexOutOfBounds exception.

The adapter is connected to a ListView.

Adapter:

```java
public class SearchActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> videoList;
    ArrayList<String> filteredList;

    public SearchActivityAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.search_activity_listitem);
        this.context = context;
        this.videoList = list;
        this.filteredList = videoList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder_search viewholder;
        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_activity_listitem, parent, false);
            viewholder = new ViewHolder_search(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            viewholder.image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_view_image);
            viewholder.videoName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_view_textview);
        }
        else{
            viewholder = (ViewHolder_search) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.d("setting value for position---",String.valueOf(position));

        String name = "";

        name = filteredList.get(position);
        name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        viewholder.videoName.setText(name);


        Glide
                .with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .centerCrop()
                .load(filteredList.get(position))
                .into(viewholder.image);


        return convertView;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return videoList.size();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
                    filterResults.values = filteredList;
                }
                else
                {
                    String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (String name : filteredList) {
                        String original =name;
                        String tempname = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                        tempname = tempname.toLowerCase();
                        if (tempname.contains(query)) {
                            result.add(original);
                        }

                    }
                    filterResults.count = result.size();
                    filterResults.values = result;
                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                Log.d("filtered list---", String.valueOf(filteredList));
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
2020-11-30 01:16:01.115 29689-29689/com.testapp.test3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testapp.test3, PID: 29689
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.testapp.test3.SearchActivityAdapter.getView(SearchActivityAdapter.java:52)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2471)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:750)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5511)
        at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:1971)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3723)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:4158)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3964)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11840)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2994)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2659)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2673)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1977)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3405)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:548)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12095)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4761)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4259)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4329)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4287)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4295)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4259)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4329)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4287)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4295)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4259)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6854)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6966)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:194)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
2020-11-30 01:16:01.117 29689-29689/com.testapp.test3 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:181)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6937)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6989)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:925)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:737)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:663)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the problem was `ArrayAdapter<String>`.
When I removed that and added `BaseAdapter` it worked.

BaseAdapter code:

```java
public class TestSearchActivityAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> videoList;
    ArrayList<String> filteredList;

    public TestSearchActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.videoList = list;
        this.filteredList = videoList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder_search viewholder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_activity_listitem, parent, false);
            viewholder = new ViewHolder_search(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            viewholder.image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_view_image);
            viewholder.videoName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_view_textview);
        } else {
            viewholder = (ViewHolder_search) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Log.d("setting value for position---", String.valueOf(position));

        String name = "";

        name = filteredList.get(position);
        name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        viewholder.videoName.setText(name);


        Glide
                .with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .centerCrop()
                .load(filteredList.get(position))
                .into(viewholder.image);


        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
                    filterResults.values = filteredList;
                } else {
                    String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (String name : filteredList) {
                        String original = name;
                        String tempname = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                        tempname = tempname.toLowerCase();
                        if (tempname.contains(query)) {
                            result.add(original);
                        }

                    }
                    filterResults.count = result.size();
                    filterResults.values = result;
                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                Log.d("filtered list---", String.valueOf(filteredList));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

    }

}
```